How to calculate COEs from State Vectors in Left Handed XYZ Coordinate System/C++
I'm making a little space sim with C++ and SDL and am trying to calculate the classical orbital elements (COEs) using the methods demonstrated in this video:



The big difference is I'm using a left handed XYZ coordinate system where X[1, 0, 0] is right, Y[0, 1, 0] is up and Z[0, 0, 1] is forward as opposed to the standard right handed IJK system which I believe represents right/forward/up (correct me if I'm wrong).
In the videos first example, given state vectors R -7000j km and V 7500k km/s we should get:
a = 6916km,
e = 0.0122,
i = 90deg or PI/2,
omega = 270deg or 3PI/2,
arg perigee = 180deg or PI,
v = 180deg or PI
but my program is giving me:
a = 6920km,
e = 0.0115,
i = 1.5707 or 90deg,
omega = 2.3561 or 135deg,
arg perigee = 0.78539 or 45deg,
v = 3.14 or 180 deg
The tiny differences don't bother me, it's just the obvious ones like omega and perigee. I suspect it must be the difference in cross product between the two coordinate systems.
This is how my program is calculating them:
void Rocket::CalculateCOEs(const CelestialBody& centralBody)
{
    Vec3Double rV = position - centralBody.position;

    // Semi Major Axis
    double u = G * centralBody.mass;
    double r = rV.Magnitude();
    double E = (velocity.MagnitudeSquared() / 2) - (u / r);

    semiMajorAxis = -u / (2 * E);

    // Eccentricity
    Vec3Double eV = (rV * (velocity.MagnitudeSquared() - u / r) - velocity * (rV.Dot(velocity))) * (1 / u);
    double eM = eV.Magnitude();
    
    eccentricity = eM;

    // Inclination
    Vec3Double hV = rV.Cross(velocity);
    Vec3Double kV(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    inclination = acos(kV.Dot(hV) / hV.Magnitude());

    // Longitude of Ascending Node
    Vec3Double nV = kV.Cross(nV);
    Vec3Double iV(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    double nM = nV.Magnitude();
    
    ascLongitude = acos(iV.Dot(nV) / nM);
    if (nV.z < 0.0)
        ascLongitude = PI_2 - ascLongitude;

    // Argument of Perigee
    argPeriapsis = acos(nV.Dot(eV) / (nM * eV.Magnitude()));
    if (eV.y < 0.0)
        argPeriapsis = PI_2 - argPeriapsis;

    // True Anomally
    trueAnomaly = acos((eV.Dot(rV) / (eM * r)));
    if (rV.Dot(velocity) < 0)
        trueAnomaly = PI_2 - trueAnomaly;
}

Here are the vector methods:
double Vec3Double::Dot(const Vec3Double& v) const
{
    return x * v.x + y * v.y + z * v.z;
}

Vec3Double Vec3Double::Cross(const Vec3Double& v) const
{
    return Vec3Double(
        y * v.z - z * v.y,
        z * v.x - x * v.z,
        x * v.y - y * v.z);
}


It does make a difference, we end up hitting a quadrant check for ascending node, but it returns 314 deg/5.497787 rad, and argument of perigee is 135 deg/ 2.3561950 rad now

Right, COE stands for Classical Orbital Elements, which are the parameters that define an elliptical orbit.

Thanks! I'm just curious, are COEs and Keplerian elements two names for the same thing or are there some differences? I'm just curious.

My cross product was giving me a wrong z-value so I fixed it, then for checking the angle between the K Vector I just used the negative Y-Axis.
